# Spring JMS: Creating multiple connection to a queue

Tags: spring, jms

To process a large number of messages coming to a queue i need guarantee of at least one jms connection to be there at any time. I am using spring and spring allows to have multiple sessions on a single connection only. In case one and only connection fails, application will come to standstill till spring reconnects to the JMS bridge.

So how can i create more than one connection to a queue in Spring, also how can i do connection pooling here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this depends on whether you are using Spring inside a J2EE container(jboss etc.) or in a standalone application.

Standalone - you'll find pooling connections to be a problem. Springs SingleConnectionFactory can be setup to renew the connection on an exception garaunteeing that at some point a connection will come online and start processing the queue again, but you'll still have the problem of waiting for that single connection to renew, plus depending on what messaging implementation your dealing with and how it does load balancing you may find yourself stuck with a connection to a single node in a cluster.

If you are running in a container you can rely on the containers connection factory which will be much more robust. JBoss Messaging in the container for instance will failover seamlessly to other nodes and handles pooling under the covers, but if your working in the container its usually easier to bail on JMS template which kind of sucks and use whatever that container provides.